# How to implement a Custom DataType in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

We would like to type various properties in Java.
e.g. the e-mail address

But now I get the message all the time:

```
Could not set field value [test@test.de] value by reflection : [class customer.email] setter of customer.email;

Can not set dataType.EmailAddress field customer.email to java.lang.String
```

How should I proceed?

```
@Entity
public class customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private EmailAddress email;
}


public class EmailAddress {

    public String value;

    public EmailAddress(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public boolean setValue(String s) {
        this.value = s;
        return true;
    }

   public String mailbox() ...
   public String host() ...
   public String tld() ...
}
```

Getter and Setter from HibernateDefaultType not called.

EDIT:
At the end. I want to store a String in the database with the email-Address. In Java I want the EmailAddress Object.

Comment: How should this be stored in the database? Will you create a email type in the database as well

Comment: please update your question and describe if you want to persist the `EmailAddress` class in the db or want to store just the email-string as varchar-column in the customer-table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is much easier. An AttributeConverter make it very easy.

https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-attribute-converter/

Thank you very much

EDIT:
Here is the Code:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class EmailAddressConverter implements AttributeConverter<EmailAddress, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(EmailAddress emailAddress) {
        return emailAddress.value;
    }

    @Override
    public EmailAddress convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        return new EmailAddress(s);
    }
}
```

And in the Entity:

```
@Convert(converter = EmailAddressConverter.class)
private EmailAddress email;
```

Comment: You should not just post a link but some code how exactly you solved your problem. This could also help others.

Answer (score -1):

Here is some example of making your own custom type.

```java
public class EmailAddressDescriptor extends AbstractTypeDescriptor<String> {

    protected EmailAddressDescriptor() {
        super(String.class, new ImmutableMutabilityPlan<>());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(String value) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String fromString(String string) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <X> X unwrap(String value, Class<X> type, WrapperOptions options) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <X> String wrap(X value, WrapperOptions options) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SqlTypeDescriptor getJdbcRecommendedSqlType(JdbcRecommendedSqlTypeMappingContext context) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

Then you would make the Email address class with all your methods

```java
public class EmailAddress extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<String> {
    private String value;

    public EmailAddress() {
        super(new VarcharTypeDescriptor(), new EmailAddressDescriptor());
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "EmailAddress";
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolve(Object value, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner, Boolean overridingEager) throws HibernateException {
        return null;
    }

}
 public String mailbox() ...
   public String host() ...
   public String tld() ...
```

How you would use it with your entity will be something like this

```java
@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "emailAddress", typeClass = EmailAddress.class)
public class customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Type (type = "emailAddress")
    private EmailAddress emailAddress;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: as an extra resource, you can refer to this as well. [custom-hibernate-types](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types)

Comment: Thank you for your Code, but the Error Message still the same.